# How to make InsertionSort faster?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, object, children

So I've got this code

```
   class Child{
    public:
        string code;
        float avg;
        unsigned int distance;
        int month;
        bool isSmallerThan(Child child, char *ordering_chars);
    };

    bool Child::isSmallerThan(Child child, char *ordering_chars) {
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            if(ordering_chars[i] == 'a'){
                if(avg == child.avg)
                    continue;
                return avg < child.avg;
            }
            else if(ordering_chars[i] == 'd'){
                if(distance == child.distance)
                    continue;
                return distance < child.distance;
            }
            else if(ordering_chars[i] == 'm'){
                if(month == child.month)
                    continue;
                return month < child.month;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    void InsertionSort(Child *array, int n, char *ordering_chars){

        Child temp;
        int i, j;
        for(j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            temp = array[j];
            for(i = j - 1; (i >= 0) && array[i].isSmallerThan(temp, ordering); i--)
            {
                array[i+1] = array[i];
            }
            array[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
```

I have an array of Child objects and I want to sort it by different fields, depends on ordering_chars array which is taken from stdin. For example if ordering_chars is ['a', 'd', 'm'] it means if avg is equal, than sort it by distance, if it is equal too, than sort it by month. The code is working, but it is to slow with large data. Have you got some solutions to make this work more efficient? I was thinking about using function pointers but I'm not sure how to do this exactly.

PS. I have to use InsertionSort, it can't be any other way of sorting, also I am not able to use STL, it's because this code is meant to go on Online Judge (I'm not taking part in any kind of competetives, just do it to test myself and to learn something).

Comment: Do you have to use Insertion Sort? Insertion Sort is known to be a relatively inefficient algorithm.

Comment: Unfortunately yes It has to be InsertionSort, but it can be modified a little.

Comment: The first mistake you made is to write your own sorting algorithm and expect it to perform. C++ comes with a quicksort implementation that's probably well optimized. Study what that code does to get ideas of how to improve your code. Also, for any question like "how to make this faster?", you must measure, so go and get a so-called profiler and use that on your code.

Comment: You may be able to make very small gains, but they will typically not be significant. You could unroll loops in your comparison, and swap big blocks of children instead of one Child at a time - I doubt you can make this even 30% faster. The big time-waster is your sorting algorithm, which you write cannot be changed.

Comment: Yes, there are efficient sorts in C++, but the point is I have to read my own implementation of exactly this (Insertion) sort. This code is not meant to be used in real life. It is more like educational thing.

Comment: @JerryM., insertion sort is not a bad thing when used judiciously. In particular, `std::sort` resorts (at least, in MS implementation) to insertion sort when a range contains less than ~30 elements.

Comment: Yeah I mean Insertion Sort isn't horrible for minute data sets, but in the general CS community, you will typically see merge sort or other sorting algorithms for bigger data sets. Good point though @Evg

Comment: @Shacerr please don't vandalize your question. Remember the purpose of StackOverflow is to help future readers with the same problem. This question is answered and actually is not a bad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is too slow because you are making a lot of copies for your Child variables.

change `Child::isSmallerThan` to take Child& by reference not by value.
and also change the Child tmp. Put it inside the loop and change it a reference as well.

Also as you suggested you can optimize the comparison function.
Make 3 lambdas one for each latter case that return an int -1, 0, 1 for lesser, equal or greater:

```
auto get_comparator(char c) {
  if (c == 'a')
   return +[] (Child& x, Child& y) { /* compare x.avg and y.avg */ }
  if (c == 'd') 
   return +[] (Child& x, Child& y) { ... }
  if (c == 'm')
   return +[] (Child& x, Child& y) { ... }
}
```

inside your InsertionSort you can create your compare function:

```
auto comp_first = get_comparator(ordering_chart[0]);
auto comp_second = get_comparator(ordering_chart[1]);
auto comp_second = get_comparator(ordering_chart[2]);

auto comparator = [comp_first, comp_second, comp_second](Child& x, Child& y) {
  int rez = comp_first(x, y);
  if (rez != 0) return rez == 1;
  rez = comp_second(x, y);
  if (rez != 0) return rez == 1;
  rez = comp_third(x, y);
  return rez == 1;
}
```

and use that one to compare the Children

Comment: Good advice - but If you follow it, then make sure to time the difference to find out how much faster it goes!.

Comment: Is there a reason this uses non-const references? (I use const by default, ie const unless I specifically want to modify an object)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException no reason not to use it, const is preferred, just didn't want to scare people with too long code

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid a lot of small swaps by performing only one, at the very end, once you find the correct position for an item. In code (beware, not tested - off-by-one errors may lurk unseen),

```
for(int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
   Child temp = array[j];
   int swaps = 0;
   for(int i = j-1; (i >= 0) && array[i].isSmallerThan(temp, ordering); i--) {
      swaps ++;
   }
   if (swaps) {
        // make space & place new element where it belongs
        // beware: this may be problematic for more complex classes
        memmove(array+i+2, array+i+1, swaps);
        array[i+1] = temp;
   }
}
```

The other source of savings would come from a faster comparison function. See [Bob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52817545/15472) for a possible implementation. Without using lambdas, I would go for

```
bool Child::isSmallerThan(const Child &o, char *ordering_chars) const {
    int m = month == o.month ? 0 : month < o.month ? 1 : -1;
    int d = distance == o.distance ? 0 : distance < o.distance ? 1 : -1;
    int a = avg == o.avg ? 0 : avg < o.avg ? 1 : -1;

    switch (ordering_chars[0]) {
      case 'a': a <<= 2; break;
      case 'd': d <<= 2; break;
      case 'm': m <<= 2; break;
    }
    switch (ordering_chars[1]) {
      case 'a': a <<= 1; break;
      case 'd': d <<= 1; break;
      case 'm': m <<= 1; break;
    }

    return a+d+m > 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't your algorithm Selection Sort rather than Insertion Sort?

Comment: Oops, correct. Fixing it as I write. I always tend to mix the two.

Comment: Fixed, now using single-swap insert-sort.

Comment: Now think about what would happen if one of the fields in `Child` was a smart pointer to an object that had a virtual destructor.

Comment: I think you *may* be ok if you use memcpy/memmove everywhere, i.e. including the copy to & from `temp`. But not when using copy constructor for some array elements and bitwise copy for others.

Comment: The current Child class has no such pointers. I have added a disclaimer.